# Discussion: should we feed the original features as inputs to an ensemble model?

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-modeling

Let's imagine you have different models to give predictions on the same topic.
One of your model is a regression, the other an ANN, the last one XGBOOST.
Some of your models work better predicting at week+1, other at predicting week+3.

Each of your model has interesting results.
How to best combine them into a strong one ?

My intuition is that you must feed the various forecasts to a new ensemble model, but also provide some of the initial features, so the ensemble model can learn in which case it is best to trust which original model.

I extensively red about Ensemble Modelling and it always seem that the only inputs are the forecasts of the base models, so no features.

Am I missing something or my intuition would be interesting?

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is called [**Meta-Learning**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_learning_(computer_science)) ("learning to learn"). And yes, those models learn from the output of other machine learning algorithms. If you have different predictions for different days into the future you might find a way to incorporate that into the meta learning model to weight the distinct model contributions over the given (prediction) time horizon.